# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, python-unittest

I want to pull the length of an input that is entered into a website's text box to see the max amount of characters that it will allow. The HTML says that the max length is 40 so I am trying to enter 41 characters to see if it will only take the first 40 characters entered. When I run the code that I have, I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

This is my code so far:

```
def test_FN_SPmax(self):
    time.sleep(3)
    first_name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/section/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/fieldset/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(
        ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(41)))
    time.sleep(2)
    typedValue = first_name.get_attribute('value')
    size = typedValue.length()
    print(size)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first_name
```

is not a web element anymore cause you did use `.send_keys`

so do this instead :

```
first_name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/section/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/fieldset/div/div[2]/input')
first_name.send_keys('something here')
time.sleep(2)
typedValue = first_name.get_attribute('value')
```

Should work for you.